# how to use js.coffee file in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

In `assets/javascripts/products.js.coffee`:

jQuery ->

```
$('#product_category_name').autocomplete

source: ['foo','food','four']
```

In `products/_form` view page:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :category_name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :category_name %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

In `layouts/application.js.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> 
**<%= javascript_include_tag 'products'%>**
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

In `assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( products.js )
```

I am new to `coffee` script. In my app i have an autocomplete field 'category_name', which is used to search the categories.I already created a file name `products.js.coffee` but can't find out how to use it.Is there anything I have missed? Maybe adding some include tags to application.html.erb? Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually rename product.js.coffee file to product.js. Just include the product.js file in application.js

Whether the file .js extension or js.coffee extension, Rails uglifier compiles and mififies the file to js file.

So, If you write coffe script code, then it will be compiled to javascript file.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-compression